# Trigger what does new.filed and old.field represent

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to learn what the new.field and old.field represent

Lets assume we are using a AFTER UPDATE Trigger

In a row/record we fields a, b, c

c is updated so it has a value before the new entry old.c and the new value new.c

if I want to reference the filed a is it old.a or new.a or does it make any difference

Answer (score 1):

In an update trigger, fields that are not changed by the update should have OLD.field and NEW.field values that are the same.

from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to
>   access columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are
>   MySQL extensions to triggers; they are not case-sensitive.
>
> In an INSERT trigger, only NEW.col_name can be used; there is no old
>   row. In a DELETE trigger, only OLD.col_name can be used; there is no
>   new row. **In an UPDATE trigger, you can use OLD.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of a row before it is updated and NEW.col_name to refer to
>   the columns of the row after it is updated.**
>
> A column named with OLD is read only. You can refer to it (if you have
>   the SELECT privilege), but not modify it. You can refer to a column
>   named with NEW if you have the SELECT privilege for it. In a BEFORE
>   trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW.col_name = value
>   if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a
>   trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to
>   update a row. (Such a SET statement has no effect in an AFTER trigger
>   because the row change will have already occurred.)

Comment: Thanks, I spent time looking for it but could not find it.